# How to use execv() with cd command in linux?

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables, cd, execv

Where is the cd command file path and in which environment variable?!
i use PATH environment variable but i don't find the cd command in it, so i want to execute the cd command in execv, thank you in advance, my code :

```
char * envVariable = get env("PATH");
execv(path, args);
```

Comment: executing `cd` is pointless. you'd be firing up a shell, changing the dir in the shell, the exiting the shell - leaving everything else exactly as it was before.

Comment: It's required in my OS lab assignment...i don't know how!!

Comment: `cd` is a shell built-in and is *not* a command. You could use `chdir()` to change directory.

Comment: If you want to execute a command, you need to fork before ! If you want to see a recoded command executer : https://github.com/charvoa/42 / And the Builtins shall be hard coded !

Comment: The current directory is associated with the current process, but it's not an environment variable. Some shells set `$PWD` to the current directory, but that's just a convention; there's no guarantee that `$PWD` will continue to match the current directory, and `chdir()` doesn't touch any environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding a shell - or something similar, you are *required* to have `cd` be a *builtin* calling the [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) syscall.

This is required when you change any property which is private to processes. The current directory is such a property (and so are limits set by [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html), etc...)

This explains why you cannot do `system("cd /tmp");` the `system` function is forking a `/bin/sh -c` process, and that shell is changing directory, not the parent process (your program).

Read [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: Then i shall stop the command input and have to search for the argument of the command (the directory needed) in the current path...etc.

Comment: If by "the current path" you mean the current value of `$PATH`, that's not relevant. The `cd` command, in its usual form, passes its argument to `chdir()` (though it might recognize some special cases like `cd -` to change to the previous directory).